When using matplotlib, how do I set the on-screen lengths of the x and y axes to be equal without changing the limits of either axis?
I would like to make the axes of a matplotlib plot a square, and do so by stretching or compressing the scaling of the axes rather than by changing the axis limits.  How can this be done?
(In other words, I am seeking a Python analog of the MATLAB command axis square.)
So far, I have tried:

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal').  This seems to equalize the scaling, rather than the on-screen lengths, of the x and y axes, consistent with the matplotlib documentation.  The axes of the resulting plot are not square unless ymax - ymin = xmax - xmin, where xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax are the axes limits (and this equality does not hold for my plot).

plt.axis('equal') and plt.axis('scaled').  These seem to provide the results shown and described in this post.  In general, the axes of the resulting plot are not square.



If I understand correctly then I think what you're looking for is ax.set_box_aspect(1) (also see here), which will give you square axes with the same limits as the original plot.
Example:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 200)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
fig.tight_layout()


